# Is there a way to change character sets for C# projects in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know that character sets can be changed in C++ projects (Unicode, Multi-Byte, etc.) , but are there any options to set character sets in c# projects?

Comment: What kind of character sets are you talking about?

Comment: Like Unicode, Multi-Byte character sets.

Comment: No, C# is thoroughly modern and only uses Unicode.  If you actually have a need to convert a byte-encoded string then use Encoding.GetString().

Comment: I'm asking whether you are talking about character sets of the source files or the characters sets used at runtime for strings and such.

Comment: Character sets used for strings, specifically.

Comment: A `string` [is a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) "*sequence of UTF-16 code units*". There are no options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All string objects in .NET are UTF-16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0). If you are interacting with native code via P/Invoke, there is a [`CharSet` field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset?view=net-5.0) on the `DllImportAttribute` which controls how .NET strings are converted when passed to / from native code.

Edited to add: C# 11 will introduce [UTF-8 literals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#utf-8-string-literals), but these literals are typed `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`, so the above still holds: regular `string` objects are UTF-16.